# Having an issues with list comprehension

Tags: python

```
def divisble_numbers(a_list, terms):
    b_list = [x for x in [a_list] if (x % [terms] == 0)]
    c_list = [x for x in b_list if all(x % [terms] == 0)]
    return c_list

divisble_numbers([2,3,5,1,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [2,3])
```

Returns this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'list'`

I am trying to get to get a list of the index that is divisible by both terms. I am confused on the error I am getting, very new to list comprehension would appreciate any help.

Comment: What should the mod of an integer with a list be equal to? what should `x % [term]` give you?

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close. This code should work:

```
def divisble_numbers(a_list, terms):
    return [x for x in a_list if all(x % term == 0 for term in terms)]

print(divisble_numbers([2,3,5,1,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [2,3]))

# Output:
# [6, 12]
```

There are two list comprehensions happening here. One is `x for x in a_list if ...`. The other one is inside the `all`: `x % term == 0 for term in terms`.

Comment: Thank you, quick question why do we need the 2nd for loop? I though that the all function would iterate through the list?

Comment: `all` goes through an iterator and makes sure everything in it is true. So first you need an iterator over all the terms that says `True` when `x` is divisible by that term. `x % term == 0 for term in terms` gives you such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your list comprehensions are good, but you've accidentally wrapped a few things in square brackets, such as `[terms]`, which don't need to be because they are already lists. `[terms]` will produce a list containing a list.

Second, the error that you were getting is because you were taking the mod (%) of a list. The mod operator only works between numbers.

```
def divisble_numbers(a_list, terms):
   b_list = [x for x in a_list if (x % terms[0] == 0)]
   c_list = [x for x in b_list if (x % terms[1] == 0)]
   return c_list
```

Comment: Note that this function will just return the list of numbers divisible by the second term in the list. (In fact, you may as well delete the `b_list = ...` line, since its result is completely ignored.)

Answer (score 0):

```
b_list = [x for x in a_list if x%(reduce(lambda x,y : x*y, terms))==0]
```

Input :

```
a_list, terms = [2,3,5,1,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [2,3]
```

Output :

```
[6, 12]
```

Your function will be :

```
def divisble_numbers(a_list, terms): return [x for x in a_list if x%(reduce(lambda x,y : x*y, terms))==0]
```

Comment: I believe this code is actually incorrect. E.g. try `a_list, terms = [4], [2, 4]`.